# localstorage returning object on reload

Tags: vue.js, session-storage

i am using vue.js with vuex

In my vuex action i am calling an external api like this:

```
 //actions.js
 getStudent({ commit }) {
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            student.getStudent()
                .then(response => {
                        localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(response.data.userData))
                        commit('UPDATE_USER_INFO', JSON.stringify(response.data.userData), { root: true })
                        resolve(response)
                })
        }
 }
```

In this function userdata is set as a localstorage item.
I also call a mutation with commit

when this function is executed for the first time everything works fine with for example this code:

```
//state.js
const userInfoLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userInfo"))

const setUserRole = () => {
    const userRole = userInfoLocalStorage ? userInfoLocalStorage.role : 'student'
    return userRole
}

const state = {
    Role: setUserRole()
}
```

Now whenever i reload the page **JSON.parse** returns the error **Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1** and when i remove JSON.parse it returns **[object Object]**. But when i use JSON.stringify it returns a json object but this works only on first load.

I find it very confusing

Please help me clear out what i should use for best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```js
const userRole = userInfoLocalStorage ? JSON.parse(userInfoLocalStorage).role : 'student'
```

You're calling `JSON.parse` on an object (`userInfoLocalStorage`) that has already been deserialized with `JSON.parse` on the line above:

```js
const userInfoLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userInfo"))
```

Instead, just do `const userRole = userInfoLocalStorage ? userInfoLocalStorage.role : 'student'`

Comment: Thanks, but this was just some code from testing and not the problem causer. Sorry. I fixed my mistake

Comment: What do you see when you inspect the local storage via the F12 dev tools in the browser?

Comment: I see [object Object]

Comment: But you get the expected result if you `console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data.userData))` inside `then` in your action?